# Parsing a JSON formatted string to object with react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, fetch-api

I'm completely new to react.
I've made some simple app that received a string from backend.

The string looks like:

> "[{"name":"David", "age":"20"},{"name":"Michael", "age":"10"}]"

Now I managed to make it into a string and render it the the web site and I can't find the right way to make this string into a object and access its values to create a table that will show the different objects details.

I have found a function `JSON.parse(obj)`,
but I guess I'm using it wrong.

I'm adding my code from App.js that at the moment is rendering on the web site.

```
function App() {

  const [items, setItems] = useState([])

  // Using useEffect for single rendering
  useEffect(() => {
    // Using fetch to fetch the api from
    // flask server it will be redirected to proxy
    fetch("/data")
      .then((res) => res.json()
        .then((data) => setItems(data))
      );
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {items.map(item => {
        return <pre>{JSON.stringify(item)}</pre>
      })}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Why are yoy stringifying the response?

Comment: The `item` in your `map()` call will be the object so you can just access its properties as usual `return <div>Name: {item.name}, Age: {item.age}</div>` (you're missing a parenthesis after `res.json()` in your example code.)

Comment: Just to note, you don't need to manually `JSON.parse()` because [`res.json()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/json) does it for you.

Answer (score 0):

You just simply need to do this:

```
    return(
        <table>
          <thead>
            <th>name</th>
            <th>age</th>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {items.map((item: any) => {
              return (
                <tr>
                  <td>{item.name}</td>
                  <td>{item.age}</td>
                </tr>
              )
            })}
          </tbody>
        </table>
    )
```

`res.json()` already converts your data to JSON, so you don't need to do anything extra. You are good to go to use your data.

in your `.map()` method `item` is the object which you need to use and access its property by simply doing `item.propertyName` as you can see in the code I shared.